# Does TRANSACTION/COMMIT/ROLLBACK only work on certain MySQL engines such as InnoDB?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, transaction

Are transaction functions only relevant for particular database engines on MySQL, or are transactions supported under all MySQL engines, including MyISAM and InnoDB?

[someone says here that transactions only work in some tables types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594391/mysql-rollback-by-error-handler-not-working)

Answer (score 3):

The only storage engine ("table type") that supports transactions with the standard MySQL 5.x distributions is InnoDB.  MyISAM and the others do not support transactions.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html